# Это сообщество не соответствует своей справке

Tags: обсуждение, причины-закрытия, тематика

Мой [последний вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1511996/) закрыли с комментарием "почитай справку". В справке написано, что следует задавать вопросы о реальных проблемах. С какой это стати, господа модераторы, проблема распространения своего софта перестала быть реальной?

Comment: Из справки (какие вопросы не стоит задавать): "Вопросы, касающиеся использования программного обеспечения, если они не относятся к программированию или системному администрированию."

Comment: А распространение своего софта - это реклама, то есть спам.

Comment: @Зонтик, реклама - это предложение за деньги, а о деньгах в теме речине было.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Касательно фактов, приведенных в вопросе

> С какой это стати, господа модераторы

Данный вопрос закрыли не модераторы.
Данный вопрос закрыли участники сообщества в ходе голосования в очереди проверок.

---

> закрыли с комментарием "почитай справку"

Вопрос был закрыт с пометкой: `невозможно дать объективный ответ.` 
Комментарий со ссылкой на справку под Вашим вопросом тоже имелся, но он был написан в корректной и уважительной форме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Касательно сути закрытия Вашего вопроса

Я один из тех, кто голосовал за закрытие вопроса.

Я стараюсь не закрывать вопросы без комментариев и в Вашем случае я не просто закрыл вопрос, а указал Вам в комментарии ровно то, что Вы просили - список площадок, на которых можно разместить и продвинуть свои программные продукты.

Одну из причин закрытия я также указал в комментарии.
Возможно, мне стоило описать её подробнее, но мне они казались очевидными и до меня уже были оставлены комментарии о причинах закрытия.

---

### Почему я проголосовал за закрытие вопроса

**У меня было ровно 2 причины так проголосовать**

- мне казалось, что данный вопрос является оффтопиком
  Заданный Вами вопрос относится **к области маркетинга**.
  *(я обычный человек и могу ошибаться.

  если кто-то приведет мне аргументы против - я их с радостью рассмотрю)*
- Данный вопрос был просто некачественным

Я обращу Ваше внимание на то, что вопрос закрыт с пометкой: `невозможно дать объективный ответ`.

Это значит, что ответы на данный вопрос, не могут привести к однозначному результату.
Они

- могут помочь,
- могут не помочь,
- а могут сделать только хуже.

Стратегия продвижения это то, что не может работать одинаково для всех. В каждом случае она будет разная. И в Вашем вопросе невозможно предположить какой именно она должна быть.

**Вы не указали тип приложения**

- мобильное приложение
- консольная утилита
- серверное ПО
- десктопное приложение
- плагины и расширения для других программных продуктов
- игры

**Вы не указали целевую платформу:**

- Windows
- Linux
- MacOS
- Embedded, etc

Статегии продвижения ПО во всех этих случаях совершенно разные, и каждый кейс может быть развернут на целую серию статей по продвижению своего продукта. И даже тогда Вам никто не сможет дать гарантий, что указанная информация хоть как-то поможет.
*(Что неприемлимо на StackOverflow)*

И все это скорее всего **будет относиться к сфере маркетинга**
(*именно поэтому я считаю данный вопрос оффтопиком*).

---

StackOverflow - это не только база знаний.
С такими вопросами Вы бы могли обратиться к сообществу в чате, и там бы Вы могли получить то, чего бы Вы хотели: живое обсуждение данной проблемы с идеями, вопросами, предложениями и реальным опытом.
Там, как мне кажется, лучшее место для подобных обсуждений.

Comment: Из запрета субъективных вопросов у нас есть единичные исключения: литература, [списки IDE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3592/). Имеет ли смысл ввести такое же исключение для сайтов-каталогов ПО (так же, с преобразованием в вики)? Вопрос не по теме, но довольно специфичен для индустрии разработки ПО, так что это было бы не самой плохой идеей.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, это хорошее замечание. Над этим как минимум можно будет подумать и обсудить.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight не во всех отраслях такие списки можно составить, но я попытаюсь в ближайшие пару дней собрать кое-какие списки и могу поднять вопрос об исключении.

Comment: Спасибо. Теперь стало яснее. Как я могу найти такой чат?

Comment: @Грузчик https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--

Answer (score 5):

Вы процитировали не весь [абзац](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Здесь можно задать любой вопрос, относящийся:
>
> - к реальной проблеме, встречающейся на практике, решение которой можно изложить кратко в паре абзацев, и которая уникальна для
>   разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального
>   администрирования IT систем.

"Вопрос распространения программ" не является проблемой, "которая уникальна для разработки программного обеспечения и профессионального администрирования IT систем.".

Comment: Почему? Из формулировки как раз следует, что является. Вопрос распространения программ - это то, что интересует именно людей, относящихся к индустрии разработки ПО, а не кого-то другого.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Для меня из формулировки это не следует. Я считаю, что это проблема не уникальна для разработки (даже если с натяжкой к ней относится).

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight Но стоит добавить, что я обычно не трактую правила настолько формально. Если ТС добавит в оригинальный вопрос достаточно подробностей, то я, вероятно, не буду голосовать за закрытие

Comment: @nomnoms12, я уточнил детали вопроса в нём же.